# How to convert a vector eps file to pdf?

Tags: pdf, converters, vector-graphics, eps

I have a EPS file in vector format that I need to convert to PDF, retaining its vector format.  I'm using a Windows 7 system, and I'm trying to find a tool that I can redistribute with my application.  It can't be GUI or online based; I need my application to use it as a library or via a system call.

I have tried the following tools without success:

- ghostscript 9.06 - ps2pdf - Outputs a blank pdf.
- ImageMagick - Generates a pdf with the correct image, but it's a raster converter so it does not preserve the vector format.
- UniConvertor - Outputs a blank pdf.
- pstoedit - Outputs a blank pdf.

Of course, I'm not an expert with any of these tools listed so it's quite possible I'm just not running the tool with the correct configuration; if anyone recognizes a blank pdf as being a symptom of an incorrectly configured run with one of the tools, please let me know of possible fixes.  Thank you for any help.

Here is the header of the eps file:

```
%!PS-Adobe-2.0 EPSF-1.2
%%Creator:Adobe Illustrator(TM) 1.1
%%For:OPS MANUAL FLOE
%%Title:ILLUS.MAC
%%CreationDate:7/27/87 3:40 PM
%%DocumentProcSets:Adobe_Illustrator_1.1 0 0
%%DocumentSuppliedProcSets:Adobe_Illustrator_1.1 0 0
%%DocumentFonts:Courier
%%+Helvetica
%%BoundingBox:000 -750 650 50
%%TemplateBox:288 -360 288 -360
%%EndComments
%%BeginProcSet:Adobe_Illustrator_1.1 0 0
```

Comment: If Ghostscript produces a blank page then its likely there was some kind of error, did you get any error messages ? Which version of Ghostscript are you using ? Can you provide a link to the EPS file ? Its hard to say anything concrete without seeing it. As far as I'm aware ImageMagick uses Ghostscript to handle PS/EPS/PDF files, so it seems like this ought to work if you get the command correct.

Comment: I've edited the question to specify the version of ghostscript.  All the runs described above were performed without error messages.  Unfortunately, I can not provide a link to the EPS file because it is proprietary data.  I don't believe ImageMagick will work for me regardless of configuration since it is a raster converter only and vector format must be preserved, but I'm hoping some of the other tools might if I can configure it correctly.

Comment: The only thing that springs to mind is that you might possibly have the EPS positioned off the page. You should check the %%BoundingBox comments at the start of the EPS file. You could also try GSView which uses Ghostscript, but does DSC comment parsing for EPS files. Other than that, there's nothing I can say without access to the PostScript program.

Comment: Thank you for your help; I've edited the question with header comments from the eps file.  Do these values look incorrect?  If so, how do I fix them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bounding box says the marks extend from 0,-750 to 650, 50

So almost the entire content (750/800) is below the page. Note that Ghostscript *ignores* DSC comments, they are, after all, comments.

In order to position this on the page, you must translate the origin and potentially scale the page. Please note that EPS files are intended for inclusion in other documents, not for printing on their own, and its up to the document manager to read the BoundingVox comments and position the EPS correctly.

In the absence of a document manager, you will have to do this yourself. Note that changing the *comments* will have no effect at all.

I would suggest you start by  prepending the line:

```
0 750 translate
```

which will move the origin 750 units vertically and so the page will then extend from 0,0 to 650,800 and see what effect that has.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help - it does seem to be a bounding box issue.  Running ps2pdf with the -dEPSFitPage option also produces good results.